# Need a good approach to test a Factory Class in Google Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am new to google test and relatively new to C++ in general. Looking at the following simplified example, what could be a good general approach to test CDeviceCreator? Do I necessarily need a mock. I have read about mocking in google test but having difficult time understanding it. Can you please provide an example specific to this case. Thanks in advance.

This is the interface for the factory class

```
class IDeviceCreator
{
public:
    IDeviceCreator(){
    };
    virtual ~IDeviceCreator(){
    };
    virtual IDevice * CreateAnalogDevice() = 0 ;
    virtual IDevice * CreateDigitalDevice() = 0 ;
};
```

Given that: CAnalogDevice and CDigitalDevice are implementing IDevice

This is the concrete factory class

```
class CDeviceCreator : public IDeviceCreator
{
public:
    IDeviceCreator(){
    }
    virtual ~IDeviceCreator(){
    }
    virtual IDevice * CreateAnalogDevice(){
        IDevice * anlogDev;
        anlogDev = new CAnalogDevice();
        return anlogDev;
    }
    virtual IDevice * CreateDigitalDevice(){
        IDevice * digDev;
        digDev = new CDigitalDevice();
        return digDev;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method CDeviceCreator::CreateAnalogDevice calls the constructor CAnalogDevice.  Most likely, the real constructor should not actually be called during your unit-tests: Probably its use would cause 'annoyances', like a) introducing hardware dependencies and thus making it impossible to run the unit tests on a development environment rather than the target system, b) increasing build time if the respective code is large or, again, links a lot of other code, c) possibly the library is not complete yet or in a buggy state, d) ...

For this reason, you would like to isolate your code from this real constructor and use a replacement instead.  You have several possibilities to achieve isolation:

- Using (dirty) preprocessor tricks like #defining CAnalogDevice to something else in a unit test.
- Linking against your test specific implementation of CAnalogDevice.  This implementation could be a mock, but in this simple example most likely something simpler (like a stub) might do just as well.

Summarized: You don't necessarily have to use a mock, but most likely you will have to do something to achieve isolation.  And, certainly this all holds in the same way for CDigitalDevice.

There are some additional recommendations you might find valuable:

- You should make it a habit to initialize values at the point of definition.  That is, instead of writing

  ```
  IDevice * digDev;
  digDev = new CDigitalDevice();
  ```

  prefer

  ```
  IDevice * digDev = new CDigitalDevice();
  ```
- Some people (including myself) like to use const just everywhere.  For example, after putting changing the initialization as shown above:

  ```
  IDevice * const digDev = new CDigitalDevice();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are right that using the real constructors creates hardware dependencies. At least for my specific case.